# Understanding and using 'this' in jQuery function

Tags: jquery, this

I have a function that I would like to apply to different elements - or rather, different selectors creating different contexts. How can I modify the below function to use `$('this')`, instead of specifying the `$('#themes')` selector inside the getClass function?

The code:

```
$('#themes').change(function(e) {
  getClass(this, e); 
});

function getClass() {
  var classToAdd = $('#themes').find('option[value]:selected').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(' ');
  var allClassess = $('#themes').find('option[value]').map(function() {
    return this.value ? this.value : null;
  }).get().join(' ');
  $('#result').removeClass(allClassess).addClass(classToAdd);
}
```

See [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zc4v96ho/).

Comment: In event listeners, `this` points to the current element the event is fired for, so you shouldn't re-select the element by a selector, use `this` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event has a `currentTarget` property that's exactly what you're looking for, and no need to pass `this` to it... in fact, just reconfigure the binding like this:

```
$('#themes').on('change', getClass);

function getClass (event) {
  var themes = $(event.currentTarget);
  var classToAdd = themes.find('option[value]:selected').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(' ');

  var allClassess = themes.find('option[value]').map(function() {
    return this.value ? this.value : null;
  }).get().join(' ');

  $('#result').removeClass(allClassess).addClass(classToAdd);
}
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Just as a tip, jQuery's binding behavior is to always pass the event like this. Generally speaking, if you need more data than the event itself you probably have an opportunity to make the binding more generic somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

the `this` operator has to do with scoping and what the current object is you are working on. If no object is currently selected then `this` will reference `document`, also known as the entire webpage. You could assign a new variable to the passed selector, that is a fairly easy way to accomplish what you are doing:

```
('#themes').change(function(event) {
  getClass(this, event);
});

function getClass(elem, e) { //if you pass args into a func, you need to declare them in the prototype
  //elem now represents whatever object you passed it (in this case 'this')
  var classToAdd = elem.find('option[value]:selected').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(' ');
  var allClassess = elem.find('option[value]').map(function() {
    return this.value ? this.value : null;
  }).get().join(' ');
  $('#result').removeClass(allClassess).addClass(classToAdd);
}
```

The other option is to use a method or jQuery plugin, but that syntax is a little bit more to grapple with than this function. Understand how this function is taking in the object as a variable before moving forward with methods and plugins.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` instead of `this`. 
That way you don't have to define the same jQuery-selector.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand the distinction between `$(this)` and `this`

`$(this)` - is a jQuery object containing `this`, so you would use `$(this)` whenever you want to run any jQuery functions

`this` - is a Javascript object, so any Javascript functions you want to use, you should use it on `this`.

Moreover, when using `this`, what it is, is dependent upon how the function is called. You shouldn't need to pass `this` and `e` to your `getClass` function. A simple `$('#themes').change(getClass);` will execute that function when `#themes` changes, and your `this` keyword in your `getClass` function will be the select object that is `#themes` while `$(this)` will be your jQuery object that contains `this`.

So instead, you can just use `$(this).find(':selected')` and you should be good. However, keep in mind, your `this` keyword inside of your `map` function refers to the object that you are running the `map` function on (aka the `$(this).find(':selected')`)